# Automatically click button on page load

Tags: javascript, button, authentication, click, auto

I'm a little stuck on creating an automatic page to press a 'log in' button which runs a javascript, submitting the form automatically isn't good enough as it simply doesn't log the user in (it's a javascript login system - as a test), instead, it will just return an error: http://prntscr.com/m1f1f6 it needs to automatically on load 'press' the log in button: http://prntscr.com/m1f1ur in order to perform the action of sending to "./main.php" which has an 'isLoggedIn' function.

```
<button class="btn btn btn-block" id="btnLoginMain">Log in</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure that your JavaScript file is referenced or deferred until after your html is loaded (placing your JavaScript just before the closing </body> is one way.)

Then in your JavaScript run:
document.querySelector('.btn').click()

Comment: This sort of worked, just needed to tweak something and now it's perfect. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this is not a good approach to make the customers/users to logging in. You can use cookie or sessions to auto login your user. Still, if you want to click the button auto on web page loading you can use the below script.

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
$("#btnLoginMain").click();
}
</script>
```

use this in the header file of your html file. If you want to click the button after some time of page load use the setTimeout() function.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger this click only once after page load automatically. ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need click there. Check the source code, what happen when you click that button and replicate it in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking it is not needed to log in. Copy and paste your code for when you do press the button, and just make it appear when the page starts up.